# How do I put a working menu behind a PNG image with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a PNG image which I need to put inside a menu, like the image below:

[image]

I'm using the `position: absolute` and `z-index` properties to accomplish this. But when the menu is behind the PNG image it won't work at all. How can I make a mask from PNG image so in that area the menu works fine?

Comment: An incredibly complex way to do it would be with three layers: The front layer would be your menu completely transparent, which your user would interact with. The middle layer would be your png image. The far back layer would be your menu again, but not transparent. You would need to link the back layer to the first layer so that the user can actually see what they are doing in the front layer. (Again, this is what I could come up with off the top of my head, not the most elegant solution ever)

Comment: I think I should use clip path! But I do not know how to make a custom clip path from a shaped png image!

Comment: Try using`mask-image` in css

Comment: Both `clip-path` and `mask` aren't supported in IE at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could leave it as is and just apply this style to the image :

```
img {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Disadvantage is that it won't work in IE10-.

http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: Nice and Clean Trick, but unfortunately it is important to support older versions of browsers!

Comment: Yeah, neat property with great support if IE weren't spoiling the party. A cross browser approach would be more complicated, I guess using JS would be easiest to "redirect" any clicks or hovering.

Answer (score 1):

Try masking the menu with your image like

```
<div id="menu">
    <!-- put your menu here -->
</div>
```

**css**

```
#menu{
        width:your_menu_width;
        height:your_menu_height;
        -webkit-mask-image: url(image_path.png);
        -o-mask-image: url(image_path.png);
        -moz-mask: url(image_path.png);
        mask-image: url(image_path.png);
}
```

Comment: I think we should invert the image. currently it will keep none transparent area and all of the transparent area will be lost! How to invert the mask?